# please solve this diffrential equation question on power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

In the differential equation $y'' + (x-3)y' + y=0 $ of power series 
at $x_0=2$ , I took $ y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n $ ,then I tried to solve this but not getting the answer. if someone solve this it will be pleasure.

Comment: If it's a differential equation and the exponents on $y$ refer to derivatives, make the notation $y''$ for $y^2$ and $y'$ for $y^1$ (if that's what it means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets start with 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x-x_0)^{n-1}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(n-1)(x-x_0)^{n-2}
$$

combining it into the differential equation we find

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(n-1)(x-x_0)^{n-2} +(x-3)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x-x_0)^{n-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(x-x_0)^{n} = 0
$$

now we need to get everything into a single summation i.e. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(...\right)=0$

To do this we shift the index of summation so for we can instantly sort out the second-drivative term with y as

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)+ a_{n}\right](x-x_0)^{n}
$$
what about the first order derivative term, well we expand the factor (x-3) to yield two equations
$$
(x+3)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x-x_0)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x-x_0)^{n}  -3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x-x_0)^{n-1}
$$
the first term on the right hand side is already in a form we want, but the second term needs to have the indices shifted again to yield
$$
(x+3)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}n(x-x_0)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{n}n - 3a_{n+1}(n+1)\right](x-x_0)^{n}
$$
combining the equations with the $\left[...\right]$
we find that the series solution must satisfy 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)+ a_{n}n - 3a_{n+1}(n+1) + a_{n}\right](x-x_0)^{n} = 0
$$
or

$$
a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)- 3a_{n+1}(n+1) + (n+1)a_{n} =0 \implies (n+2)a_{n+2}- 3a_{n+1} + a_{n} = 0
$$

check it for yourself though :).

Comment: hey I need to talk with you in chat, I've somany doubts.

Comment: Is there something wrong with what i wrote? or something you don't understand?

Comment: in the 3rd row , 2nd term contains x-3, there is an error

Comment: oops..I will check it out.

Comment: fixed it, it didn't change the overall workings by much. Can you solve the last recursion relation that i get to?

Comment: and also I wanna know what do actually the second order and higher order differentials mean?

Comment: how do you mean? higher order differentials? the equation is a second order linear differential equation for which you are trying to solve by series solution?

Comment: ya I solved then, but didn't the answer. I will put answer here later, please check it hmmm

Comment: of course, I asked a diff. eqn. but want to know the geometrical interpretation of higher order differentiation

Comment: ok then. So are you satisfied with the answer, and can continue with the finding the solution with $x_{0}$ or do you need me to complete it?

Comment: I suggest that you put that in to another question "what is the geometrical inter. of the second order derivative and higher orders" as this is beyond the scope of this particular question. But please check this site for other occurrences of this question, and be specific as such a question can be closed down if certain criteria are not met.

Comment: no no its ok, but what's the answer of 2nd one

Comment: oh really! alright

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13271/discussion-between-chinny84-and-mahavir)